# SQL file failing to import into MySQL workbench- "Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing column 'userid'"

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Ive been trying to import a .SQL file and I know the database works. Can someone please explain why I am getting the below error whilst importing from self-contained file?
**ERROR 3734 (HY000) at line 55: Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing column 'userid' for constraint 'user_app_FK' in the referenced table 'user'**

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 8.0.12, for Win64 (x86_64)
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1    Database: avi_it
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   8.0.12

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
 SET NAMES utf8 ;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;





DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `application`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 ;
CREATE TABLE `application` (                          --line 55
  `applicationID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jobID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `applicationDes` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`applicationID`),
  KEY `user_app_FK_idx` (`userID`),
  KEY `job_app_FK_idx` (`jobID`),
  CONSTRAINT `job_app_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`jobID`) REFERENCES `job` (`jobid`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_app_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`userID`) REFERENCES `user` (`userid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user`; 
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 ;
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `personID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userID`),
  KEY `person_user_FK_idx` (`personID`),
  CONSTRAINT `person_user_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`personID`) REFERENCES `person_detail` (`personid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Comment: The dump must contain foreign key checks disabling statement - somewhere at the top of  the dump. If you receive shown error message then this statement either is absent or is not executed by some reason.

Comment: ive added the checks in my question above, will uncommenting these work?

Comment: `/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;` saves current settting then disables FK checks. Maybe Workbench cuts this row off by some reason? try to uncomment this row and complementary row at the end of the dump.

Answer (score 0):

should be just order issue. need to first create the user table